# Authentication Error in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am new to Kubernetes. I am getting below error while creating deployments in Kubernetes.

```
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->
```

Can anyone give me solution for this?

I am using below command to setup deployment

```
 kubectl run my-app --image=gcr.io/<dockeraccount>/<dockerrepository>:dockerimagetag
```

Comment: This error happens when you try run a Jenkins Job?

Comment: what is the docker image you are running? and for which command you are getting the above output? are you getting the error message from the logs of your docker container? or is it coming from kubernetes events?

Answer (score 1):

I found this same error in StackOverflow, problably that you problem it's about your authentication *anonymous*

If help you: [JENKINS Authentication Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394445/jenkins-authentication-fails)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I am not using Jenkins Job. I have enabled Kubernetes from docker for windows. I am directly running command to create a pod, so there is no interaction with Jenkins.

Comment: You try pull some image using Docker directly?

Comment: Yes, I am able to pull the image directly from docker